# if I'm only using a server to host webpages, should I be using SELINUX?

Tags: linux, selinux

On my server, I have static and dynamic websites. Yes there are api links, but they aren't exactly open to the public. When is it appropriate to SELINUX? would this be an appropriate example of a good time to use it (to dispel hackers)?

Answer (score 0):

Any time is a good time to learn and use SELinux. It cuts down on the potential attack vectors that are available to attackers if your system becomes compromised.

It's become a pretty industry-standard part of hardening web servers or any kind of other server for that matter. Instead of asking *"when should I be using this"* you should be asking *"do I have a compelling reason **not** to use this?"* and the answer will almost always be "no."